# Каким образом можно из класса потомка обратиться к методам\атрибутам класса родителя?

Tags: c++

Не могу нагуглить конкретный ответ

Comment: В java для этого используется super. В c++ возможно тоже.

Comment: Конкретный ответ вы не нашли, а что вы пытались сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Можно явно указать, к какому классу мы обращаемся. Например,

```
class Base {
public:
    void BaseMethod();
}

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void DerMethod() {
        Base::BaseMethod();
    }
}
```

Но вообще это необязательно. Если нет конфликтов имён, то и так будет выбран нужный метод/атрибут. То есть в данном случае можно просто написать `BaseMethod();`

Comment: Только надо учесть правила доступа. `private` член дозваться не получится...